# Flutter : Sharing Multiple Images Outside the App with Descriptions

Tags: flutter, dart, share-plus

I am working on adding functionality to share multiple user-selected images and their descriptions outside the app, such as on WhatsApp or Instagram. Currently, I am using the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package.

When sharing a single image with a description, it displays well on WhatsApp. However, when attempting to share multiple images, an issue arises. The problem lies in the fact that when sharing multiple images with descriptions, all images end up having all descriptions.

[image]

[image]

What I desire is to have each image accompanied by its own individual description. Unfortunately, the current behavior results in all images sharing the same set of descriptions.

Here is my code example for sharing multiple images

```
Future<void> shareMultipleShoes(List<XFile> imageList,String descriptions) async {
await Share.shareXFiles(
    imageList,text: descriptions
);}
```